# Is there atomic broadcast in akka?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I need atomic broadcast and I want to use akka cluster.

I'm not sure is there atomic broadcast in akka, so I just want to ask, to be sure.

I know, there are such things like `DistributedPubSubMediator.SendToAll` aswell as `Cluster Aware Routers`. Does any support total order broadcast ?

By atomic (total order) broadcast I mean, actor A sends broadcast bA aswell as actor B sends broadcast bB (in parallel & from another node). Eventually, (every actor receives message bA before bB) or (every actor receives message bB before bA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only ordering guarantee offered by Akka is that messages sent from actor `A` to actor `B` will be received in order for that pair of actors.  Messages from other actors to actor `B` could be received before, after or interleaved with the messages from `A` to `B`.

So no, Akka does not provide the ordering guarantee you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

By default there is no such guarantee as messages are sending asynchronously. But you can just use some mediator `X` (any actor including `DistributedPubSubMediator`) which will induce such guarantee: send `(bA, recipients)` from `A` to `X`, send `(bB, recipients)` from `B` to `X`, and `X` should just broadcast every message to its recipients (it will be "atomic" and sequential, as done inside one actor).

If you need to do this in cluster - you could try ["Cluster Singleton"](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/cluster-singleton.html) to avoid single point of failure by sacrificing high availability and maybe partition-tolerance (you will have to remove nodes manually from the cluster to allow the "P")

Comment: Yes, it will work, however this implies single point of failure. Luckily, there are algorithms for that.

Comment: you could try ["Cluster Singleton"](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/cluster-singleton.html) to avoid single point of failure by sacrificing high availability and in some cases partition-tolerance (you will have to remove nodes manually from the cluster to allow the "P")